# OpenCV Getting number of pixels depands on colour in POI

Tags: opencv

I've configured already POI (Point of Interest) on my HSV image. How can i get number of pixels in the same colour from that Point of Interest and save that number to one variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following,

1. Perform [inRange()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) for specified color  on the HSV image.
2. Now [countNonZero()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) on thresholded image(out put of inRange).